# Azure Pipline Error: Failed to get Firebase project project-name. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it

Tags: firebase, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Duplicate Question: [By Uber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473787/error-failed-to-get-firebase-project-project-name-please-make-sure-the-project), previously asked for `google-cloud-firestore`

My question is Related to Deploy Firebase from Azure DevOps. I have a list of tasks in my CI Pipeline which are running fine but the one `firebase publish` job consistently getting failed.

**Error:**

[image]

Also, I have put my token inside variables

[image]

**install firebase tools:**

[image]

**firebase publish:**

[image]

How can this be solved? what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue comes from the usage of your variables.

See all of the variables usage:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax

[image]

You can find that no usage like this:

`$key`

I think it should be:

`$(key)`

In your situation, the issue should comes from $FIREBASE_TOKEN itself was been recognized as string `"$FIREBASE_TOKEN"`, the actual value was not pass in.